# Parameter count mismatch with Invoke call

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

I'm tried set new value of `label` in Thread exectuion, using the following code:

```
private void DoWork()
{
    Invoke( new SetLabelMethod(SetLabelValue), 
        new object[] { string.Format("running {0}({1})", nome, id) });
}
```

call the function:

```
th = new Thread(DoWork);
th.Start();

public delegate void SetLabelMethod(string msg);
private void SetLabelValue(string msg)
{
    label.Text = msg;
}
```

it give an `Parameter count mismatch` how fix it?

Comment: Where is closing curly bracket for the `new object[]`? What is signature of the Invoke() method? Is it `Control.Invoke(Delegate, Object[])` ???

Comment: What is the target of `Invoke`?

Comment: It was my mistake typing here.

Comment: You didn't say what the target of the call to `Invoke` is. Without that we are stuck. What is `this` when you call `Invoke`?

Comment: Penalty can't close the topic.

Comment: I give up. You still didn't say what the target is.

Answer (score 1):

The code you've posted is correct. What line of code is throwing the exception?